# Border guards didn't cancel the stamp, when I went to the wrong gate

Tags: schengen, borders, passport-stamps

I mistakenly went through passport control and they put me a stamp in my passport, then it turned out that I was at the wrong gate and I returned back. Border guards did not cancel the stamp. Should I care in this situation?

Comment: From your summary, it is not very clear what actually happened. To get an answer, you will have to clarify a lot what exactly happened. If you have an exit stamp from the Schengen area, but still are in the Schengen area, then yes, you should care.

Comment: It depends a lot on your nationality, whether you are on a visa or avail of visa-free travel, and your recent and future travel plans. Not being stamped in or out is not unheard of (there are quite a few questions about that here), so they can deal with it, but it may complicate things in some situations.

Comment: The type of visa, if any, also matters. The mistaken entry may have used up a single entry visa.

Comment: Was it an entry stamp or an exit stamp?  Didn't you have to go back through passport control in the other direction to get to the correct gate?  Didn't they put a corresponding exit or entry stamp when you did so?

Answer (score 3):

Lacking the **relevant** information makes answering this difficult.

If you were in **Transit**:

- yes, you will have a problem, since in the future they will see that you entered without a proper exit stamp and will assume that you overstayed.

Since the burden of proof lays with you, retain the ticket proving that you entered and left that airport. If you have an entry stamp for the another country you traveled to will also help (Remember to mention that on your next entry and they ask questions about this).

---

If you just sent to another gate to enter

- no, since you already had an entry stamp a second one is not needed

---

If both of the scenarios don't apply

- then you will simply have to add the **relevant** information to your question.